# How to match blender with AZERTY keyboard?

Tags: edit-mode

I people, I just downloaded Blender and begin watching tutorials but I don't find how to match my AZERTY keyboard with the app.. (I'm from Belgium)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could just enable another keyboard layout to switch to when using Blender.

Comment: If using Windows you can set it up so that using Windows + Spacebar will switch between an AZERTY and a QWERTY Keyboard. Windows icon > Settings > Time and Language > Language > Prefered languages > click on language to get the Options tab > Add a keyboard > Choose the Uniterd Kingdom QWERTY option. Done. Now whenever you use the Windows + Spacebar combination the keyboard layout will toggle between the 2 layouts. You can see the change in the Taskbar bottom right. This method has the inconvenience that also using the keyboard combination SHFT + ALT also switches keyboards!

Answer (score 0):

I've looked through blender's settings and I don't think it is possible to use a non-QWERTY keyboard (in the typical way). That being said, there might be a few workarounds:

- Change a few of the shortcut keys (go to edit/preferences/keymap and change the keys)
- Use the widgets for navigation instead of the keyboard shortcuts

[image: navigation widgets]

*These are the navigation widgets*

- Press 'F3' and search for the function (e.g. move, extrude, inset, etc.) instead of using the keyboard, then press 'enter' to use the function[image]

Answer (score 0):

Me and most French-speaking blenderians I know haven't had major issues using AZERTY layouts:

Most keys are available on AZERTY in the first place, and you end up customizing your keymap to your liking anyways.

And since the big keymaps purge back in v2.80, there are even less QWERTY-specific keys and more room to assign custom keys.

So unless you have a specific function that you miss (in which case you can easily remap it), it's not that big of a deal.