# Blender 3.5 interprets AZERTY as QWERTY keyboard layout

Tags: interface, shortcut

I have just moved to Blender 3.5 and now Blender interprets my keyboard layout as [QWERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY) instead of [AZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY). When I want to extrude a face, for instance, instead of pressing <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd>, I have to press <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>W</kbd> to get the correct result.

Does anybody know how I can make Blender recognize my AZERTY keyboard layout?

Edit : in fact, the <kbd>Z</kbd> is correctly interpreted when I edit a text in Blender. The problem seems to appear only when I use <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: Blender should automatically import the keymap settings you had in your previous Blender version. There's just one previous question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191233/how-to-match-blender-with-azerty-keyboard) on SE but it's just about setting up blender to use an azerty keyboard.

Comment: Previous version was uninstalled before installing 3.5...

Comment: In that case you'll have to set the keymap up again! You do know that you can have several Blender versions installed (and running) at once don't you?

Comment: Yes, of course, but the old habit to always use only the latest one pushes me to uninstall olders to save disk space. Do you know if there is a file I could restore to retrieve the key map?

Comment: You haven't said what OS you're using, but under Windows all the previous setup files appear to be Blend files here: "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\<version>\config\userpref.blend" and Linux ones are here: "/home/Username/.config/blender/<version>/config/userpref.blend". They aren't deleted by an uninstall and I assume launching the 'userpref.blend' file will start Blender with that version's settings but I've not tried it!

Comment: Using Windows. Copying "userpref.blend" and "startup.blend" from "3.4" folder to "3.5" folder unfortunately doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas in that case. :^(

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me anyway.

Comment: I think this is a bug. If it works in the Text Editor, but doesn't with modal operators, this means modal operators do not take keyboard input correctly. You should report it.

Answer (score 0):

As previous members have commented, Blender should recognize the keymap that was used from previous versions provided that it wasn't deleted or moved.

However, if that is not the case, I'd recommend adjusting the keymap settings at **Edit > Preferences > Keymap** to match the settings that you wish to use. Blender also has functionality to import and export keymaps, so it may also be useful to export your keymap settings once created to another location for safe storage between version upgrades.

Blender unfortunately hasn't had a ton of easy solutions for users with non-QWERTY keyboards since v2.80, so it may just be something that either requires getting used to or some time spend remapping keys to a more logical layout.